# Display a child of a child in a category

Tags: php, wordpress, categories

I have main categories that have children

**Structure:**

```
1.Products
2. Bakery
    2.1 - Breads
    2.2 - Rolls
    2.3 - Buns
3.Cookie
    3.1 - Cakes
    3.2 - Cake
    3.3 - Croissants
4. Ice cream
    4.1 - Fruity
    4.2 - Cream
```

On **archive.php** i want to display child of `current category`. I'm using this:

**archive.php**

```
<?php
    $term = get_queried_object();
    $children = get_terms( $term->taxonomy, array(
        'parent'    => $term->term_id,
        'hide_empty' => false
    ) );

    if ( $children ) { 
        foreach( $children as $subcat ){
            echo '<li><a href="' . esc_url(get_term_link($subcat, $subcat->taxonomy)) . '">' . $subcat->name . '</a></li>';
        }
    }
?>
```

The above returns to me the structure without childrens:

**Structure:**

```
1. Products
2. Bakery
3. Cookie
4. Ice cream
```

I have no idea how to display children of children according to my "structure"now. Have u any idea? Thanks!

Comment: Does WP give all information on all children levels? If yes, this could be a simple recursive function, maybe? Take the category as argument and if children is not empty, call the same function with each child. Only do nothing if a category has no more children.

Comment: Check this - https://wp-kama.com/function/wp_list_categories You need to use child_of + deph in order to get list of all subcats